# Objective C MAX macro bug

Tags: objective-c, macros

I'm seeing strange behavior with the MAX macro in Objective C.  Specifically, I have this code in my main function:

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray array];
NSLog(@"[array count] - 1 = %d", [array count] - 1);
NSLog(@"MAX(0, [array count] - 1) = %d", MAX(0, [array count] - 1));
NSLog(@"MAX(0, -1) = %d", MAX(0, -1));
```

The output is:

```
[array count] - 1 = -1
MAX(0, [array count] - 1) = -1
MAX(0, -1) = 0
```

I saved the preprocessor output with -save-temps, and it looks like this:

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray array];
NSLog(@"[array count] - 1 = %d", [array count] - 1);
NSLog(@"MAX(0, [array count] - 1) = %d", ((0) > ([array count] - 1) ? (0) : ([array count] - 1)));
NSLog(@"MAX(0, -1) = %d", ((0) > (-1) ? (0) : (-1)));
```

All the necessary parentheses are there, and `[array count] - 1` has no side effects, so the usual macro issues shouldn't apply.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`[array count]` returns a `NSUInteger` -- in other words, an unsigned integer.  So `[array count] - 1` is not -1, it is ((NSUInteger)-1), which is 0xFFFFFFFF or something like that -- which is greater than zero.

But then when you take 0xFFFFFFFF and pass it as an argument to `NSLog(@"%d")`, NSLog treats it as a signed integer (because you used %d).

Comment: I didn't notice that the return value was unsigned, but it makes sense.  Thanks!